# java method to highlight characters in a string

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

Since I am not the smartest person, I wonder what could be done differently on this latest method I coded in Java.

This method highlights certain characters in a string, that are passed through a character array to the method, by putting them in brackets. What would you do differently?

```
static String highlightCharsInString(String arg1, char[] arg2) {
    char[] arg1Char = arg1.toCharArray();
    int arrLength = ((arg1Char.length) * 2) + arg2.length;
    char[] hlChars = new char[arrLength];
    int a, b = 0;
    int y = 0;
    boolean match=false;
    //System.out.println(arg2.length);
    for(a=0; a < arg1Char.length; a++) {
        match=false;
        for(b=0; b < arg2.length; b++) {
            if (arg1Char[a] == arg2[b] && arg1Char[a] != ' ') {
                match=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(match==true) {
            hlChars[y] = '(';
            y++;
            hlChars[y] = arg1Char[a];
            y++;
            hlChars[y] = ')';
        }
        else {
            hlChars[y] = arg1Char[a];
        }
        y++;
    }
    String hlCharsString = new String(hlChars);
    return hlCharsString;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly your code works as expected, you just want to "optimize" it (by some metric: readability, speed, ...), right? If so, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question.

Comment: My two cents: I don't see why you define `a` and `b` outside of the loop instead of the traditional `for(int a=0; ...`. Also: your variable names are pretty bad, bordering on meaningless.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this, hope this helps!

```
static String highlightCharsInString(String text, char[] charsToHighlight) {
    for (int i = 0; i < charsToHighlight.length; i++){
        text = text.replaceAll(String.valueOf(charsToHighlight[i]), "(" + charsToHighlight[i] + ")");
    }
    return text;
}
```